# Stuck in understanding PCA objective function

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, machine-learning, covariance, principal-component-analysis

I am trying to understand the objective function of PCA. Intuitively I understand that we are trying to find the direction where the variance of the projected data points on that direction is maximum.

The formulation of objective function is stated here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/10256/176418

But I don't understand the first equation itself. Which is as following:

$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i x_i^T = \frac{X^TX}{n}$$

where each $_$ is a vector of $p$ features and $$ is the matrix such that the th row is $x^T_i$ (data matrix).

How summation of variance of data points ($\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i x_i^T$) is same as the covariance matrix of the entire data matrix ($X^TX/n$)?

Isn't this summation a scalar? Whereas the covariance matrix would be of size $p*p$, where $p$ is number of features as mentioned in the above reference?

The same thing is also mentioned in here: http://cs229.stanford.edu/notes/cs229-notes10.pdf (page 5), where this summation is called empirical covariance matrix.

Comment: $x_i^Tx_i$ is a scalar, whereas $x_ix_i^T$ is a $p \times p$ matrix

Comment: @DhanviSreenivasan Hmm..is that why they are calling it empirical covariance matrix? It's estimated using average of individual data points. Then the first equation should not have strict equality...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose, you've made a mistake: $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n x_{i} x_{i}^T = X^T X$  (without $\frac{1}{n}$ term) (below is python example)

[image]